# i got the error while running javascript for IE11

Tags: selenium, webdriver

below is my code :

```
package project1;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class SearchInGoogle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("Packt Publishing");
        searchBox.submit();
    }

}
```

output:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.29.1.0
Listening on port 17311
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == q (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 296 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'
System info: host: 'GNRSEZDT00035', ip: '10.210.6.68', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 00659ae5-b108-4fc4-b59c-390b1c15c879
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, elementScrollBehavior=0, javascriptEnabled=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=11, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, allowAsynchronousJavaScript=false, initialBrowserUrl=, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:299)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at project1.SearchInGoogle.main(SearchInGoogle.java:13)
```

I m getting the above error. The above code is able to open the page in IE11 but it is not finding any elements. I tried all elements and I already set the IE11's security settings. So do u have any other solution for this problem?

Comment: does it opening google.com?

Comment: This could be related to KB3025390 Windows update. Webdriver does not work on IE11 with this update. Read this link for details: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8302. You can uninstall KB3025390, try windows registry hack, or wait until Microsoft fix the bug in IE11.